# how to follow redirected url in java?

Tags: java, redirect, http-redirect

I am aware that for following redirected URLs in JAVA java.net.httpURLConnection Class could be helpful. Therefore, for this purpose following method is implemented:

```
public static String getRedirectedUrl(String url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url).openConnection());
        con.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        con.setReadTimeout(1000);
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Googlebot");
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        con.connect();
        String headerField = con.getHeaderField("Location");
        return headerField == null ? url : headerField;

    }
```

My problem is that this method unable to follow redirected urls for some of the URLs such as the following URL, However it works fine for the most of redirected URLs.
http://ubuntuforums.org/search.php?do=getnew&contenttype=vBForum_Post

Comment: That URL returns a 200 status code. It doesn't redirect. So there's no redirect to follow.

Comment: @JBNizet Please check this URL in browser. It will be redirected to another URL.

Comment: I have. Twice. And it doesn't redirect.

Comment: @JBNizet I checked the redirection through browser and it seems this URL will redirect to http://ubuntuforums.org/search.php?searchid=7345321

Comment: @JBNizet it seems new url is generated automatically by server

Comment: Now it does. But I guess this is not systematic, maybe depending on timing issues.

Answer (score 2):

> This can be help you in your case.

```
public static String getFinalRedirectedUrl(String url)  {       
        String finalRedirectedUrl = url;
        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            do {
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(finalRedirectedUrl).openConnection();
                    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    connection.connect();
                    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                    if (responseCode >=300 && responseCode <400)
                    {
                        String redirectedUrl = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
                        if(null== redirectedUrl) {
                            break;
                        }
                        finalRedirectedUrl =redirectedUrl;
                    }
                    else
                        break;
            } while (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return finalRedirectedUrl;  }
```

Comment: this method does not work with example url. that i mention in question

Comment: This code block is in working condition. I have tested it with this url also http://graph.facebook.com/439873422836340/picture?type=large

Comment: I think we have to set more specific properties to connection for your case.

Comment: I get `null` when I run `connection.getHeaderField("Location")`. Does it just mean that there was no redirection?